# How to use toArray in Laravel Lighthouse Resolver?

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

When I use `first()` in query builder I get result. See:

```php
public function __invoke($_, array $args)
{

  return MyTable::where('id', 1)->first();
}
```

However, when I change `first()` with `toArray()`, I can not get any result. See:

```php
public function __invoke($_, array $args)
{

  return MyTable::where('id', 1)->get()->toArray();
}
```

How can I get result for `toArray()` method?

*Even I use toArray() method with get(), it does not work!*

When I use with first() method result is like that

```
{
  "data": {
    "myTableResolver": {
      "column_1": 1,
      "column_2": "XYZ"
    }
  }
}
```

When I use with toArray() method result is like that

```
{
  "data": {
    "myTableResolver": {
      "column_1": null,
      "column_2": null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because `toArray()` method belongs to  the collection results that comes from fetching query builder,
you should fetch the result using `get()` method:

```
  return MyTable::where('id', 1)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best approach is to do this:

```php
return MyTable::find(1)->pluck('some_column')->toArray();
```

Using `pluck` you can filter the columns you want to get.

Also you can use `find(1)` method instead of `where('id', 1)`.

Comment: I have already used another way. But This is an interesting approach. I will try it next time. Thnks.